# Need help with integrating the function $\frac{-cb}{b(ax+Pbe^{bx})+a}$ w.r.t. $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Can someone give me some hints on how to solve the following: $$exp\left(-\int{\frac{cb}{b(ax+Pbe^{bx})+a}\,dx}\right),$$ where $exp(t)=e^{\,t}\,\forall t\in \mathbb{R},e \approx2.71$, and $a,b,c,P$ are constants with $b\neq 0$?

(It is possible that there may be no solution but I doubt it.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you tell where you found this integral ?

Comment: Nope, that has no elementary form

Comment: Hello @ClaudeLeibovici , it's nice to talk to you again. I got this integral after substituting the solution [you gave me in my previous post] into the other ODE. Now, I am trying to solve the homogeneous version of the ODE, and in order to solve the homogeneous version of it, I'll need to solve this integral. (This is part of a research project I am doing.)

Comment: @Mann : So, does that mean that there is no solution?

Comment: Yes, well wolfram alpha doesn't even give a closed form for $\frac{dx}{x+e^x}$ , however with series expansion it would be possible i believe,